# Mixed model - "Non-positive definite approximate variance-covariance"

Tags: r, mixed-model, multilevel-analysis

I estimate the following model for estimating the standard errors for random coefficients:

```
library(nlme)
Model1 <- lme(MRPK ~ 1, random = (~1|industry/id), data=Sample_Data,  control=lmeControl(opt='optim'), method="REML")
Model1$apVar
```

I am getting the following error message: "Non-positive definite approximate variance-covariance"

However, it does work with method="ML"

I am working with multiple datasets. Opposite is also true. In some datasets, method="REML" is working but method="ML" is not working.

How to identify this problem? I am very new in this literature.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any reason you are using `lme` and not `lmer` from the `lme4` package ? This is a more recent package, by some of the same authors and is better for most linear mixed models. In `lme4` you would use this syntax: `model <- lmer(MRPK ~ 1 +(1|industry/id), data=Sample_Data)`

Comment: @Robert Long I would like to use lmer but it does not give me the standard errors for random coefficients. Can I calculate the standard errors for random coefficients by lmer? Again, if I use lmer, then it gives that error. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you seek standard errors for random effects ?

Comment: @RobertLong As fixed parameters, I would like to estimate standard errors for random effects to check the statistical significance. Am I wrong?

Comment: The sampling distribution of random effects estimates is in general strongly asymmetric, so a the standard error is inappropriate. If you really need a test then a bootstrap procedure is a much better method, but personally I don't see the need for a formal test. The study/experimental design along with common sense should inform the random structure.

Comment: @Robert Long Can we add bootstrap procedure directly with lme4 code? Or I need to add separate code.  Thanks for your nice explanation.

Comment: Yes, you can use the `bootMer` function